# eliminar paginación en aleteo

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

¿Podría alguien ayudarme a eliminar la paginación de un DataTable? La información es de un JSON, la paginación apareció en el pie de página de la tabla.

Estoy empezando a aprender a flutter y realmente no entiendo por qué se está agregando la paginación a mi tabla, ¿podría alguien explicarme cómo eliminar eso?

Mi código es el siguiente ...

```
class NombreValoresTable extends StatefulWidget {
      final List<NombreValoreM> nombreValoreM;
    
      const NombreValoresTable({this.nombreValoreM}) : super();
    
      @override
      _NombreValoresTableState createState() => _NombreValoresTableState();
    }
    
    class _NombreValoresTableState extends State<NombreValoresTable> {
      //int _rowsPerPage = PaginatedDataTable.defaultRowsPerPage;
      //int _sortColumnIndex;
      bool _sortAscending = true;
      @override
      void initState() {
        _items = widget.nombreValoreM;
        super.initState();
      }
    
      void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(NombreValoreM d), int columnIndex,
          bool ascending) {
        
        setState(() {
          
        }); 
      }
```

'''
fragmento de código

'''

```
List<NombreValoreM> _items = [];
      //int _rowsOffset = 0;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    
        return Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
          children: [
            Container(
              //color: Colors.teal,
              width: width,
              height: height - 150,
              child: Center(
                child: NativeDataTable.builder(
                  
                  itemCount: _items.length,
                  
                  itemBuilder: (int index) {
                    final NombreValoreM dessert = _items[index];
                    return DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
                      DataCell(Text(dessert.nombre)),
                      DataCell(Text(dessert.valor.toString())),
                    ]);
                  },
                  header: const Text(''),
    
                  noItems: Text("No Items Found"),
                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(
                        label: const Text('Nombre'),
                        onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>(
                            (NombreValoreM d) => d.nombre, columnIndex, ascending)),
                    DataColumn(
                        label: const Text('Valor'),
                        onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>(
                            (NombreValoreM d) => d.valor.toString(),
                            columnIndex,
                            ascending)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Estoy empezando a aprender a flutter y realmente no entiendo por qué se está agregando la paginación a mi tabla, ¿podría alguien explicarme cómo eliminar eso?

Comment: Hi Jose, please translate your question to Spanish, is a rule from Stackoverflow en Español.